# CSS failed on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have the following HTML:

```
  <div class="my-select-color-items">
    <div ng-repeat="color in colors | orderBy:descricao" class="my-select-color-item" ng-click="select(color)" ng-style="bgColor(color)">
      <h1 class="title">{{color.descricao}}</h1>
    </div>             
  </div>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
.my-select-img-items,
.my-select-color-items {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.my-select-img-item:empty,
.my-select-color-item:empty {
    border: none;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.my-select-img-item,
.my-select-color-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.my-select-img-item {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.my-select-color-item {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

.my-select-color-item .title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

It works fine, like this:

http://postimg.org/image/gvkavjnsx/

The problem happens using Safari. See below:

http://postimg.org/image/tb3lrxpe3/

Does anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Best regards

Wilton

Comment: in other webkit browsers it works?

Comment: It works on Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.